# Laptop keyboard stopped functioning properly

Tags: keyboard

Basically today out of blue my laptop keyboard started acting up. For example I press "s" but I see "`s" on the screen. Some keys don't work at all.

And the weird thing is it keeps changing, in a sense that for example in the morning I press "s" and I get "`s", then few hours later "s" works correctly.. but pressing some other key output multiple characters.

Then sometimes it spontaneously will start outputting some character onto any input field that is available as soon as I click on it to gain focus. And it will just keep on going and going, as if I keep a button pressed (which I don't).

At first I thought this was a virus, but I have a dual boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu, and I get same problem on both. I even tried to boo live CD, and still had same problem.

Anyone had this kind of problem?

It's a Toshiba Satellite c660-258. It is around year old, but quite well kept. Never spilled anything on it, or dropped it. And my wireless USB keyboard works perfectly on it (appart from the spontaneous character inputs, which I can stop by hitting NUM LOCK key)

Comment: Did you try cleaning your keyboard?

Comment: nope, it is clean. I mean yeah there might be some dust there.. but other than that it is perfectly clean :)

Comment: Have you tried to take the keys off and put them on again? You should hear a click when putting them back on ...

Comment: The problem isnt that key doesnt work (some of the dont), the problem is that i press one key but get get a combination of maybe 2-3 keys output on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Goto Control Panel->Keyboard->Properties and from there you may configure the speed, character repeat, cursor blink rate and other settings.  In Hardware, see if the device is working properly, if not, you will have to reinstall the driver.  If you have an external keyboard attached to it, remove it and try to uninstall the driver for this external keyboard.  It should work all fine then.  Please try.